# How do you override @type of an item in an array in schema.org markup?

Tags: schema.org

in my @person section, I have the following

```
"alumniOf" : [
    "Google",
    "Autodesk",
    "Wikimedia Foundation",
    "Rhode Island School of Design"
    ],
```

Which resolves to

```
alumniOf    
@type   Organization
name    Google

alumniOf    
@type   Organization
name    Autodesk

alumniOf    
@type   Organization
name    Wikimedia Foundation

alumniOf    
@type   Organization
name    Rhode Island School of Design
```

the first 3 default @types are correct, but the last should be @type EducationalOrganization not Organization, how do I force the @type value?

Comment: Separately apply the correct type to each organization and then link the organization id to property.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, a sub array?

Comment: Thanks, that worked

  "alumniOf" : [
    "Google",
    "Autodesk",
    "Wikimedia Foundation",
    {
        "@type":"EducationalOrganization",
        "name":"Rhode Island School of Design"
     }
    ],